# How to replace the contents of the entire buffer in Vim

Tags: vim

How do I `:read` a file and replace the entire buffer with its contents, *without leaving a single blank line at the top of the buffer*?

---

What I'm trying to achieve is use a template when I open a new file. I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.go $read ~/.vim/templates/new.go
```

However, when I open a new `.go` file, the first line is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.go 0r ~/.vim/templates/new.go
```

Comment: This is better, but now I have a newline at the end of the file, not the beginning. Although, I can live with that, since `gofmt` will get rid of the trailing blank line when saving.

Comment: Missing a `$d_` to delete the last line

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two commands for this. One to read the file, one to delete the last line. This will work:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.go execute '0r ~/.vim/templates/new.go' | $d
```

Checkout this page for an explanation:
https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Multiple_commands_at_once